# Can't install windows 10 after wiping the partition (UEFI)

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, uefi, windows-installation

I installed Windows 10 Home by mistake on a work computer. (Used the wrong usb key.) I tried to install Windows 10 Pro after that but it didn't want to do it. (No install, only reset available. And of course reset just installs Windows 10 Home). So then I tried formatting the drives thinking that somehow I had to force the computer to wipe the previous Windows installation, as I found no way to force a reinstall of Windows 10 Pro. In the end, I used an Ubuntu boot CD to wipe all the partitions. I still can't install Windows 10 Pro. The only option I get is troubleshoot or turn off the PC. In troubleshoot, I can "reset this pc" which doesn't work, I can recover from a drive, but I have nothing to recover, and then I have "advanced options", and none of those are any more helpful.

I am pretty sure it is something about UEFI but I've been trying to reinstall this computer for 3 days and nothing seems to help. I suppose I must get rid of a signature on the disk or something similar. I don't find anything about this on google, but it is probably because I don't know the words to describe my situation.

I am probably going to install without UEFI because I have to resolve this situation, but I would like to know for the future what I did wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you removed all partitions? Can you perhaps provide a photo of the screen where you can only troubleshoot?

Comment: Most likely the system partition is still intact.

Comment: I don't see any partition in linux, is it possible that the system partition is hidden from linux?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/005929en).  Use the Windows diskpart utility.  It is available on the Windows installation medium by choosing a command prompt in the troubleshooting options.  You can look up other options for it like `convert gpt` on a disk that doesn't have any partitions on it to make it the format that a UEFI firmware, and therefore the Windows installer in UEFI mode, expects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer headkase. By the time I saw this post I had already installed using a non UEFI windows install. So I couldn't use your solution, which might have been a good one, I just don't know.

Comment: You're welcome, if you ever do convert over to GPT in the future then you really only have to do it once.  Subsequent installs from there will reuse the GPT partition table.

Answer (score 0):

From you question, it is pretty clear that you don't even see Windows Setup.

Therefore, the most logical conclusion is that your USB flash drive does not have a Windows Setup, rather, it has a Windows RE. In other words, you are using the wrong USB flash drive again.

Use another computer to examine the USB flash drive and ensure that it indeed has a Windows Setup in it. Specifically, look for folder called `Sources` and in it, look for a file called `install.wim` which is at least 3.20 gigabytes in size.

I don't even know what made you go and tinker with partitions. **You could always use Windows Store to upgrade the edition of your Windows 10 Home by supplying your Windows 10 Pro serial number.**

Comment: Thanks for your help. The flash drive I used has a setup, I am sure of it as I used it to install quite a few systems. I only had a UEFI windows pro and a UEFI windows home (got it from ms website when I had problems before). I am not sure what is windows RE, but I don't think it is what I have. Windows refused my serial number when I tried to upgrade. I know these serial numbers work as I used them on 35 computers before.

Comment: If you ignore facts, your problem won't be resolved. And the fact to which you need to pay attention right now is that you are not even seeing Windows Setup. It doesn't matter what your flash drive has done in the past; it is not doing it right now. And if you don't know what is Windows RE, see Wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_RE

Comment: Ok well... I have been using the windows install key supplied by Dell to install. But to be certain I went to the sources folder and didn't find a install.wim file but an install.swm and install2.swm file that were around 4 gb and 1.5 gb. I suppose it should work (from what I see on the web it seems to be for split windows images).

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I had to install without UEFI because something was left behind it seems. Anyway, the old school install worked.